# How Override Djoser base endpoint users/me

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I am a bit new to Djoser and what i am wanting to do is when an authenticated user naviates to the `users/me` API endpoint it returns with the user id email and name. I would like for it to also return custom information how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

While this might only answer half of your question, if you use a custom user, then you would add a REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['field_you_want_included']

E.g this is how one of my custom user profiles look like.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    user_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    receive_news = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True, default=False)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_premium = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    # FIELDS HERE WILL BE ADDED TO USERS/ME ENDPOINT
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['is_premium']
    objects = UserAccountManager()
```

There is plenty if info on making custom users with djoser, so what matters here is the required_fields list. Now, when making a get to users/me it will also include 'is_premium'.
However, for more complex inclusions I would attempt to override the view & serializer. Have not tried that myself but I will edit this post if I do.

Answer (score 0):

Djoser is just a Django App.
Just override Djoser's classes with your own and point your auth URLs to those instead of those of the package.
I had to that to, this is sample of what I did.

```py
from djoser.views import TokenDestroyView as DjoserTokenDestroyView
from djoser.views import UserViewSet

class CustomUserViewSet(UserViewSet):
    """
    Overriding djoser's Users view
    """

    @extend_schema(summary="Me", responses={200: LoginSerializer, 404: UserNotFoundResponse, 401: FailedLogin})
    @action(["get", "put"], detail=False)
    def me(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        get the current User's data and KPIs settings
        """
        if request.method == MethodsNames.GET.upper():
            user = User.objects.filter(email=self.get_instance()).select_related(ACCOUNT).prefetch_related(
                RelatedNames.AUTH_TOKEN,
                'account__bundles', 'account__bundles__bundle_kpis',
                RelatedNames.USER_SELECTED_KPIS)[0]
            user_data = LoginSerializer(user, many=False)
            return Response(user_data.data)
       # some more overriding here...
```

then my urls file look like:

```py
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from users.views import TokenCreateView, CustomUserViewSet, TokenDestroyView

users = DefaultRouter()
users.register("users", CustomUserViewSet, basename='users')

login = DefaultRouter()
login.register('token', TokenCreateView, basename='login')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(login.urls)),
    path('', include(users.urls)),
    url(r"^token/logout/?$", TokenDestroyView.as_view(), name="logout"),
]
```

instead of (from Djoser docs):

```py
urlpatterns = [
    (...),
    url(r'^auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Hey @yovel cohen can you check out my other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66722096/trying-to-override-djoser-serializer-getting-attributeerror-got-attributeerror

Comment: okay, can you just upvote if the answer helped you? @ElieFrancois

Comment: what is the point using DJOSER if the urls are not included? As far as I understand if you do not include the djoser.urls into your app then all the endpoints from djoser are not accessible through your API, right? so one cannot use, for example, the djoser registration or password_reset functionality. So then what's the point of using djoser? how does it come in handy if you don't use their urls?

Answer (score 0):

in your setting files add this

```
DJOSER = {
    # 
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'customuser.serializer.UserSerializerCreate',
        'user' : 'customuser.serializer.UserSerializer',
        },
    

}
```