# Trying to override djoser serializer getting AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field error

Tags: python, django, djoser

I am new to djoser I am user to authenicate a user. I then wanted patient information to be displayed when `user/me` is accessed but i overrode it to also show patient details as well but I go this error

Error

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `blood_sugar_level` on serializer `PatientInfoSerializer`.
```

The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `UserProfile` instance.
Original exception text was: 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'blood_sugar_level'.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager

from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings # used to retreive AUTH_USER_MODEL from settings.py file

# These two imports allow for the default user model to be customized or overrided 
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser 
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin

# Default model manager
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager 


class UserProfileManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Manager for user profiles"""

    def create_user(self, email, name, password=None):
        """Create a new user profile"""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, name=name,)

        user.set_password(password) #This hashes the user password so we do not have plain text passwordfs in our db
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, name, password):
        """Create and save a new superuser with given details"""
        user = self.create_user(email, name, password)

        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user
            

class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Database model for patients in the system"""
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    #phone?
    #address?
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserProfileManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    def get_full_name(self):
        """Retrieve full name for user"""
        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        """Retrieve short name of user"""
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        """Return string representation of user"""
        return self.email


class PatientInfo(models.Model):
    """Database model for patient information"""

    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, # This points to the user model used for authentication in settings.py, if we need to change the model used change it there
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    # Patient insulin injected choices
    YES = 'YES'
    NO = 'NO'

    IS_INSULIN_INJECTED_CHOICES = [
        (YES, 'YES'),
        (NO, 'NO'),
    ]

    inject_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, blank= False)
    inject_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, blank= False)
    blood_sugar_level = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank= False)
    is_insulin_injected = models.CharField(choices = IS_INSULIN_INJECTED_CHOICES, default = 1, max_length=3, blank= False)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank= False)
    inject_area = models.TextField(blank= False)
```

Serializers.py

```
from accounts import models
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()


class UserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('id','email','name','password')


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializes a user profile object"""

    class Meta:
        model = models.UserProfile
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'name', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {
                'write_only': True,
                'style': {'input_type': 'password'}
            }
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create and return a new user"""
        user = models.UserProfile.objects.create_user(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            name=validated_data['name'],
            password=validated_data['password']
        )

        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """Handle updating user account"""
        if 'password' in validated_data:
            password = validated_data.pop('password')
            instance.set_password(password)
 
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)   


class PatientInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializes patient Info objects"""

    class Meta:
        model = models.PatientInfo # Points this serializer to the patient info model
        fields = ('id','user_profile','inject_date', 'inject_time', 'blood_sugar_level', 'is_insulin_injected', 'quantity', 'inject_area',)
        extra_kwargs = {
            'user_profile': {
                'read_only': True,
            }
        }
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated 
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings

from accounts import serializers # Will use this to tell API what data to exect when making a POST PUT PATCH request to API
from accounts import models
from accounts import permissions

class PatientInfoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Handles creating, reading and updating patient info objects"""
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    serializer_class = serializers.PatientInfoSerializer # This points to the
    queryset = models.PatientInfo.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.UpdateOwnReading, IsAuthenticated,) # Validates that a user is authenticated to read or modify objects
    

    def perform_create(self, serializer): # overridijg this function so that when a user tries to create an object they are validated as the current user
        """Sets the patient profile to the logged in user"""
        serializer.save(user_profile=self.request.user) # This sets the user profile to the current user from the serializer passed in
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it seems that you're passing a User object to the Patient serializer, which doesn't have those fields.

try:

```py
    def create(self, serializer):
        patinet_info = PatientInfo.objects.filter(user_profile=self.request.user)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(patinet_info, many = True) # This sets the user profile to the current user from the serializer passed in 
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exceptions=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

now, the thing is that user_profile is a Foreign key, so they can be multiple users for patients according to your model.
this is why I added `many= True`
you should also notice I'm overriding the create and not the perform create method.
this is a more suitable place for that.